# Text in UITextView not display correctly, invisible, but occupied spaces

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview, word-wrap

There is a UITextView in the view, the view controller is showing with Modal style. In my viewDidLoad method, I set the text of this UITextView, but, the text is not showing. Image below showing the error. ***Text color is black***.

The weird thing is , when I long tap in the text view or tap [return] in keyboard, the text become visible.   One thing I noticed is this error only ***occurred when the text I set is longer than the UITextView frame width, and the last word is not broken such as a long url***.

I think the problem is ***maybe the word wrap not work correctly***.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Code like below:

```
UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 520, 220)];
myTextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];    
myTextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
myTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
myTextView.delegate = self;
myTextView.text = @"long text should some like http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11200726/edit";

[self.view addSubview:myTextView];
[myTextView release];
```

RESOVLED. In viewDidLoad method, add code below:

```
CGRect tempFrame = myTextView.frame;
[myTextView setFrame:CGRectZero];
[myTextView setFrame:tempFrame];
```

Comment: Could you show us the code for the UITextView? Thanks.

Comment: I've add the code. Just alloc/init, and then set, release. No other things here.

Comment: Your fix works for me too. I had the same issue even with a short text, so I think that the problem is not related to word wrapping. FYI calling [myTextView setNeedsDisplay] and/or [myTextView setNeedsLayout] does not resolve but changing the frame does.

Answer (score 6):

Subclass UITextView, to a class of your own, let's say MyUITextView:UITextView.

Initialize it offscreen with

> [[MyUITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]

In MyUITextView override the method

> -(void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow

and in it, set self.frame to the proper value.

this worked for me!

Comment: for the same problem? maybe, just reset the frame, I'll try this. thanks.

Comment: I just reset the frame in viewDidLoad method. Not subclass the text view. And, It works! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the text color is black? Also make sure that the image is behind the textView in the view hierarchy. TextView handles Word wrap automatically.

Comment: Yes, It's black. No image here.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case, the viewDidLoad is getting called before modelViewController is presented.

- Set the text after modalViewController is presented.
- If that also not working, then after presenting model, call a method to set the text explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your view hierarchy. You might have added another textView above that view.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the background color of textView. It must appear is UITextView is added there. And make sure you are not adding another view as a subview above your UITextView. If the textColor is black it must be visible, wordwrap is done by default automatically unless you change the property.Also try to check the attributes settings in XIB if added and plz show the code if adding programmatically.

Comment: I've add the code. Just alloc/init, and then set, release. No other things here.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in:

```
self.view
```

Try add this code line at top

```
self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds] autorelease];
```

And if not will help, try remove this code line

```
myTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```